How to prevent 'ProjectGraphError' in NX after deleting files
Whenever I delete or move files in my NX workspace, I often get a ProjectGraphError afterwards preventing me from launching any apps.
NX usually complains about not being able to import the files I've just deleted - even though I've removed all references to them in my other source files. Seems like there is some caching going on that hasn't caught up to the latest changes and deleted files.
When I try running nx repair I just get: No changes were necessary. This workspace is up to date!
So I'm forced to do nx reset to clear and reset the cache. But I really don't want to do that every time I move or delete a file.
Any help on how to prevent this is appreciated!
